# Phone is suspended when making outbound calls using TelephonyManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

Hello and thanks for your help in advanve,

So I've run into a problem while developing this production code. In some instances the phone seems to be freeze when making outbound calls, this code has been inherited by me to help solve this issue with refactoring and refactor the code. So I'm looking for alternative solutions as well as a fix for this issue.

So my current implementation is using a broadcast receiver to check the state of the phone in the onRecieve() method as shown below

```
public PhonecallService() {
        mApiService = new ApiService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Timber.d("ONRECIEVE Service");

        String stateStr = intent.getExtras() != null ? intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE) : "";
        String number = intent.getExtras() != null ? intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) : "";

        try {


            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            } else {
                int state = 0;
                if (stateStr != null) {
                    if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                    } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                    } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                    }
                }
                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This then should call this method and check the state of the phone to then send a broadcast like so:

```
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if (lastState == state) {
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if (number != null) {
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    savedNumber = number;
                    onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                    lastState = state;
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else {
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                lastState = state;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else if (isIncoming) {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                } else {
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                lastState = state;
                break;
        }

    }
```

This is then handled in the CallOutFragment

```
public class CallOutFragment extends BaseFragment<MainViewModel, CallOutFragmentBinding> {
    private BroadcastReceiver mKeypadBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
        }
    };
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Class<MainViewModel> getViewModel() {
        return MainViewModel.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.call_out_fragment;

    }

    public static CallOutFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        CallOutFragment fragment = new CallOutFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            if (mBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
                try {
                    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (mKeypadBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
            try {

                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mKeypadBroadCastReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            if (mBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {

                getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.PREFERENCES_CALL_OUT_CLOSE_BROADCAST));
            }
            if (mKeypadBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {

                getActivity().registerReceiver(mKeypadBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.KEYPAD_BROADCAST));
            }
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            if (!mBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
                try {
                    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!mKeypadBroadCastReceiver.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
                try {
                    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mKeypadBroadCastReceiver);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.PREFERENCES_CALL_OUT_CLOSE_BROADCAST));
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mKeypadBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.KEYPAD_BROADCAST));
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.PREFERENCES_CALL_OUT_CLOSE_BROADCAST));
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mKeypadBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.KEYPAD_BROADCAST));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        viewModel.getmDialerContactsFilter().postValue(null);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideFloatingDialer();
        }
        viewModel.getmIncomingCall().observe(this, incomingCall -> {
            if (incomingCall != null && incomingCall) {
                viewModel.getmSelectedNumber().postValue(null);
                if (!Fragments.DIALER.equals(FragmentUtils.callOutPreviousFragment)) {
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showFloatingDialer();
                }
                if (FragmentUtils.currFragment != FragmentUtils.callOutPreviousFragment && FragmentUtils.callOutPreviousFragment != null) {
                    FragmentUtils.switchFragment((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), FragmentUtils.callOutPreviousFragment);
                }
            }
        });
        String number = viewModel.getmSelectedNumber().getValue();
        viewModel.getmOutCallStatus().observe(this, apiCallStatus -> {
            if (apiCallStatus != null) {
                if (apiCallStatus.getStatus().equals(Status.ERROR)) {
                    showOkDialog("Outbound call failed please check network", viewModel.getmMode().getValue(),
                            dialog -> viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true));
                }
            }
        });
        viewModel.getmOutCallDeclineStatus().observe(this, apiCallStatus -> {
            if (apiCallStatus != null) {
                viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
            }
        });
        if (viewModel.getmConversationId().getValue() == null && viewModel.getmOutCallStatus().getValue() == null) {
            if (number != null) {
                viewModel.callRemoteNumber(number);
            } else {
                viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
            }
        }
        Pair<String, String> numberDescription = viewModel.findNumberDescription(number);
        if (numberDescription != null) {
            dataBinding.outCallName.setText(numberDescription.first);
        } else {
            if (number != null) {
                dataBinding.outCallName.setText(PhonecallService.getNumberSmart(number));
            } else {
                getString(R.string.number_unknown);
            }
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    count++;

                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        if (count == 1) {
                            dataBinding.outTextview.setText(String.format("%s.", getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.call_out_call)));
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                            dataBinding.outTextview.setText(String.format("%s..", getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.call_out_call)));
                        } else if (count == 3) {
                            dataBinding.outTextview.setText(String.format("%s...", getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.call_out_call)));
                        }

                        if (count == 3)
                            count = 0;
                    }

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2 * 500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Timber.e(e);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);

        final Handler closeHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable closeRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                if (Objects.equals(viewModel.getmIncomingCall().getValue(), false)) {
                    viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
                    viewModel.timeoutCall();
                    viewModel.getmDisplayAlert().postValue(getResources().getString(R.string.call_out_fail));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.e(e);
            }
        };
        closeHandler.postDelayed(closeRunnable, 20000);

        dataBinding.getRoot().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        dataBinding.getRoot().requestFocus();
        dataBinding.getRoot().setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                viewModel.getmIncomingCall().postValue(true);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        return dataBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

Some of my suspicions have come from how the manifest has been set up so here are the permissions set up in it alongside the receiver settings;

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.teliqo.pipcall.services.PhonecallService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This occurs quite randomly and haven't been able to generate a crash report, the only thing that has I've been able to observe is that the fragment is being called numerous times.

My question is;
1) Is there a reason as to why the phone is frozen when making a call?
2) Is there an alternative, cleaner way to implement this fix?

Thank you very much in advance and I'm open to any suggestions that could help solve this issue